# Azure KeyVault SSO

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I'm using Azure AD Domain Services. I have users connecting to Azure RemoteApp using their Azure AD accounts. When they connect to RemoteApp, I want to have a login script that fetches the a storage account access key and maps a network drive to Azure File Storage using it.

I've already put the Storage Account Access Key in the Azure Key Vault and provisioned Secret permissions for the Azure AD Domain User that connects to the Azure RemoteApp. Now how can get Login-AzureRMAccount to use the current Windows Domain User in context to authenticate? So that I can then call Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret and get the access key with which to map the network drive? I don't want the logged in user to be prompted again unnecessarily.